# My dataset has over 10,000 items, why is this not reflected in my lists?

Tags: python, list

```
# open, read, close output.txt (smaller version)
f = open("10thousand.txt", "r")
data = f.read()
f.close

# clean the data
data = data.replace('\n', '\t')
data = data.split('\t')

ageList = []

# append the data (ages) into the list
for i in data:
    ageList.append(i)

data.sort()

# print(ageList)

gen1 = []
gen2 = []
gen3 = []
gen4 = []
gen5 = []

# cycle through, add ages to our generation groups
for i in range(len(ageList)):
    if i >= 16 and i < 18:
        gen1.append(i)
    elif i > 17 and i < 34:
        gen2.append(i)
    elif i > 33 and i < 54:
        gen3.append(i)
    elif i > 53 and i < 73:
        gen4.append(i)
    elif i > 72 and i <= 101:
        gen5.append(i)
    else:
        pass
```

My lists are only showing 10-30 data points in each list even though my input file has over 10,000. I am writing this for a school final and I can't seem to figure out where the issue is.

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: Apple MacBook Pro - using IDLE

Comment: Is this python 2 or 3?  Also, why are you converting `\n` to `\t`? Does the original file have both?

Answer (score 1):

You are checking and appending the indices of the list to the generations. You need to adjust your code to reference and append the ages themselves:

```
#append the data (ages) into the list
for i in data:
    ageList.append(int(i))

...

#cycle through, add ages to our generation groups
for age in ageList:
    if age >= 16 and age < 18:
        gen1.append(age)
    elif age > 17 and age < 34:
        gen2.append(age)
    elif age > 33 and age < 54:
        gen3.append(age)
    elif age > 53 and age < 73:
        gen4.append(age)
    elif age > 72 and age <= 101:
        gen5.append(age)
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/carolinemiley/Desktop/python final /tryyyymain.py", line 38, in <module>
    if age >= 16 and age < 18:
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
>>>

Comment: I edited my answer to convert the strings from your file to integers before appending to ageList. The rest should then work.

Comment: ah, I was trying to do that in the for loop itself. thank you so much, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

- You can use `with` on the file. It will close automatically this way.
- Start out by reading the numbers into the list and converting to
  `int`.
- `.split()` splits on all whitespace characters so no need to convert
  from one `\n` to another `\t`.
- You can iterate on the list instead of looping a range.

Something like this.

```
with open("10thousand.txt", "r") as numbers:
    ageList = [int(n) for n in numbers.split()]

gen1 = []
gen2 = []
gen3 = []
gen4 = []
gen5 = []
for age in ageList:
    if age >= 16 and age < 18:
        gen1.append(age)
    elif age > 17 and age < 34:
        gen2.append(age)
    elif age > 33 and age < 54:
        gen3.append(age)
    elif age > 53 and age < 73:
        gen4.append(age)
    elif age > 72 and age <= 101:
        gen5.append(age)
    else:
        pass
```